# Need to get total counts of a record from table in database using ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to count the total rows of a table when I pass a date as a parameter.

`IService`:

```
Task<int?> ScoresUpdated(DateTime date);
```

Service implementation:

```
public async Task<int?> ScoresUpdated(DateTime date)
{
    var result = await _eventScheduleContext
                           .ViewPersonEventScore
                           .Where(x => x.DateTimeUtc.Date == date
                                       && x.ExamModeId == 1
                                       && x.EventStatusId == 8).ToListAsync();
                           
    return result.Count();
}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ScoresUpdated(DateTime date)
{
     var result = await _examDetailService.ScoresUpdated(date);
     return Ok(result);
}
```

But the output I'm getting is 0. In the database, I can see 80 rows.

Is there anything wrong with my code? Can you give me some suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: Check the date you are passing as a parameter may not be match with the DB value. Debug the date and compare it with the Database value.

Comment: I am passing date as 2022-06-19

Comment: Task<int?> Is correct??

Comment: Hi, can you share the SQL query and the result to the question? And can I know what is the `date` value.

Comment: Meanwhile, please also use tagging to mention which RDBMS that you used.

Answer (score 0):

Suspect that it is due to this line

```
x.DateTimeUtc.Date == date
```

In SQL expression, I believe it translated to

```
CONVERT(date, DateTimeUtc) = @date
```

which `@date` is `DateTime` type. So this results that you are unable to query any records.

Use `date.Date` so that the translated SQL expression will be:

```
CONVERT(date, DateTimeUtc) = CONVERT(date, @date)
```

```cs
public async Task<int?> ScoresUpdated(DateTime date)
{
    var result = await _eventScheduleContext
        .ViewPersonEventScore
        .Where(x => x.DateTimeUtc.Date == date.Date
            && x.ExamModeId == 1
            && x.EventStatusId == 8)
    .ToListAsync();
                           
    return result.Count();
}
```

While seems you are only returning the count of the query result, you may consider applying [`CountAsync<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource>, CancellationToken)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.countasync?view=efcore-6.0).

This would improve the query performance as it will return the count, but not return all columns to the result.

```cs
public async Task<int?> ScoresUpdated(DateTime date)
{
    return await _eventScheduleContext
        .ViewPersonEventScore
        .CountAsync(x => x.DateTimeUtc.Date == date.Date
            && x.ExamModeId == 1
            && x.EventStatusId == 8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason for defining optional return type for the task (Task<int?>). I suggest using Task. refer to [this Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types) for further details.

However, despite having 80 rows or entries in the DB as mentioned, you need to check which one of them match the condition you have defined (Where(x => x.DateTimeUtc.Date == date.Date
&& x.ExamModeId == 1
&& x.EventStatusId == 8))

If no entry meets the condition, the count of course would be zero.

Try removing the condition and check.